# CSS: Make children inside parent responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am not using any CSS framework like bootstrap to get responsiveness out of the box which is why I am having trouble making responsive layout.

[Please see jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ludeqafile/edit?html,css,output)

I essentially what to auto-resize colorful boxes based on browser window size eg that should shrink or grow automatically based on window size. Colorful boxes inside their parent should always be in horizontal row but should be able to adjust their width and height [like this example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8).

I tried using `flex-wrap: nowrap;` but it didn't do the trick :(

Please note that colorful boxes are using `position:absolute` with parent's position being `relative`. I am also adding `left` css property to these boxes via JavaScript to change their position for the sake of sliding animation.

```js
function Carousel(options) {
  options = options || {};

  // options vars
  let speed = options.speed || 1; // animation speed in seconds
  let width = options.width || 200;
  let height = options.height || 100;
  let space = options.space || 30;

  // other vars
  let container = document.querySelector('.carousel-container .carousel');
  let slides = container.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
  let curSlide = null;
  let prevSlide = null;
  let nextSlide = null;

  if (areSlidesPresent()) {
    setup();
  }

  // functions //

  function setup() {
    // we assume first slide to be current one as per UI requirements
    //slides[0].classList.add("current");
    curSlide = slides[0];

    // we assume second slide to be next as per UI requirements
    nextSlide = slides[1];

    // we assume last slide to be prev as per UI requirements
    prevSlide = slides[slides.length - 1];

    // position elements horizontally        
    positionSlides();
  }

  function areSlidesPresent() {
    return slides.length > 0;
  }

  this.getCurrentSlide = function() {
    return curSlide;
  }

  this.getNextSlide = function() {
    return nextSlide;
  }

  this.getPreviousSlide = function() {
    return prevSlide;
  }

  this.setNextSlide = function() {

    if (areSlidesPresent()) {
      let allSlides = [];

      // build new order of slides
      allSlides.push(nextSlide);

      // middle ones
      for (let i = 2; i < slides.length; i++) {
        allSlides.push(slides[i]);
      }

      allSlides.push(curSlide);

      // now add to DOM after cleaning previous slide order
      for (let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++) {
        container.appendChild(allSlides[i]);
      }

      slides = allSlides;

      setup();
    }
  }

  this.setPreviousSlide = function() {
    if (areSlidesPresent()) {
      let allSlides = [];

      // build new order of slides
      allSlides.push(prevSlide);
      allSlides.push(curSlide);

      // middle ones
      for (let i = 1; i < slides.length - 1; i++) {
        allSlides.push(slides[i]);
      }

      // now add to DOM after cleaning previous slide order
      for (let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++) {
        container.appendChild(allSlides[i]);
      }

      slides = allSlides;

      setup();
    }
  }

  function positionSlides() {

    curSlide.style.marginLeft = '0px';

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

      slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.width = (width) + 'px';
      slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.height = (height) + 'px';

      let elementWidth = getStyle(nextSlide, 'width');

      if (i === 0) {
        slides[i].style.zIndex = -10;
        //slides[i].style.opacity = '1';

        slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.width = (width + 50) + 'px';
        slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.height = (height + 50) + 'px';
      } else {
        slides[i].style.zIndex = 0;
        //slides[i].style.opacity = '0.7';
      }

      if (i > 0) {
        slides[i].style.marginLeft = (space * 2) + 'px';
        elementWidth = parseInt(elementWidth, 10) + space;
      }

      slides[i].style.transition = speed + 's';
      slides[i].style.left = (elementWidth * i) + 'px';
    }
  }

  function getStyle(el, prop) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop)
      .replace('px', '')
      .replace('em', '');
  }
}

// utility
function log(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

var options = {
  speed: 1, // animation speed
  width: 250, // slide width
  height: 150, // slide height
  space: 25 // space in px between slides
};

var carousel = new Carousel(options);

function selectCurrent() {
  log(carousel.getCurrentSlide());
}

function selectNext() {
  carousel.setNextSlide();
}

function selectPrev() {
  carousel.setPreviousSlide();
}
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.carousel .carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(70%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));
}

.carousel .carousel-item:first-child .carousel-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel .carousel-item .carousel-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel .carousel-item .carousel-content {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* temp css below */

body {
  background: #2C374A;
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.button {
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button:hover,
.button:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.button:active,
.button:active {
  top: 104px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Make a Call</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#0E6DE8;border:10px solid #78B1FA">Slide One</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Message</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#D90080;border:10px solid #E357A9">Slide Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Picture</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#FEC601;border:10px solid #FFDD64">Slide Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Video</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#3DB365;border:10px solid #90E0AB">Slide Four</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="navigation">
  <div class="button" onclick="selectNext()">Next</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="selectCurrent()">Select</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="selectPrev()">Prev</div>
</div>
```

Comment: " using position:absolute...  also adding left css property"  Well there's your problem right there.  If you want responsive design, don't use non-responsive techniques. HTML is responsive by default, until you tell it not to be.

Comment: Please show us the output image.

Comment: [*You are not looking for this, right?*](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/OvZwVr?editors=0100)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh: Thanks but not really, all boxes should be visible actually. With what you have done, I can see one box at a time.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh  It should be like this all visible in same row but responsive too: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem here was:**

1. Width was hard-coded in your JS, so if width is in `px` it can't be responsive.
2. By applying `position:absolute` to you `carousel-item`, it forced the children to get out of the box.

**What I did:**

1. Got rid of the static width and other functionalities related to width from your JS
2. Removed `position:absolute` from `carousel-item`

Let me know if this is what you are expecting.

```js
function Carousel(options) {
  options = options || {};

  // options vars
  let speed = options.speed || 1; // animation speed in seconds
  // let width = options.width || 100;
  let height = options.height || 100;
  let space = options.space || 30;

  // other vars
  let container = document.querySelector('.carousel-container .carousel');
  let slides = container.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
  let curSlide = null;
  let prevSlide = null;
  let nextSlide = null;

  if (areSlidesPresent()) {
    setup();
  }

  // functions //

  function setup() {
    // we assume first slide to be current one as per UI requirements
    //slides[0].classList.add("current");
    curSlide = slides[0];

    // we assume second slide to be next as per UI requirements
    nextSlide = slides[1];

    // we assume last slide to be prev as per UI requirements
    prevSlide = slides[slides.length - 1];

    // position elements horizontally        
    positionSlides();
  }

  function areSlidesPresent() {
    return slides.length > 0;
  }

  this.getCurrentSlide = function() {
    return curSlide;
  }

  this.getNextSlide = function() {
    return nextSlide;
  }

  this.getPreviousSlide = function() {
    return prevSlide;
  }

  this.setNextSlide = function() {

    if (areSlidesPresent()) {
      let allSlides = [];

      // build new order of slides
      allSlides.push(nextSlide);

      // middle ones
      for (let i = 2; i < slides.length; i++) {
        allSlides.push(slides[i]);
      }

      allSlides.push(curSlide);

      // now add to DOM after cleaning previous slide order
      for (let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++) {
        container.appendChild(allSlides[i]);
      }

      slides = allSlides;

      setup();
    }
  }

  this.setPreviousSlide = function() {
    if (areSlidesPresent()) {
      let allSlides = [];

      // build new order of slides
      allSlides.push(prevSlide);
      allSlides.push(curSlide);

      // middle ones
      for (let i = 1; i < slides.length - 1; i++) {
        allSlides.push(slides[i]);
      }

      // now add to DOM after cleaning previous slide order
      for (let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++) {
        container.appendChild(allSlides[i]);
      }

      slides = allSlides;

      setup();
    }
  }

  function positionSlides() {

    curSlide.style.marginLeft = '0px';

    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

      // slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.width = (width) + 'px';
      slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.height = (height) + 'px';

      let elementWidth = getStyle(nextSlide, 'width');

      if (i === 0) {
        slides[i].style.zIndex = -10;
        //slides[i].style.opacity = '1';

        // slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.width = (width + 50) + 'px';
        slides[i].querySelector('.carousel-content').style.height = (height + 50) + 'px';
      } else {
        slides[i].style.zIndex = 0;
        //slides[i].style.opacity = '0.7';
      }

      if (i > 0) {
        slides[i].style.marginLeft = (space * 2) + 'px';
        // elementWidth = parseInt(elementWidth, 10) + space;
      }

      slides[i].style.transition = speed + 's';
      // slides[i].style.left = (elementWidth * i) + 'px';
    }
  }

  function getStyle(el, prop) {
    return window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(prop)
      .replace('px', '')
      .replace('em', '');
  }
}

// utility
function log(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

var options = {
  speed: 1, // animation speed
  width: 250, // slide width
  height: 150, // slide height
  space: 25 // space in px between slides
};

var carousel = new Carousel(options);

function selectCurrent() {
  log(carousel.getCurrentSlide());
}

function selectNext() {
  carousel.setNextSlide();
}

function selectPrev() {
  carousel.setPreviousSlide();
}
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  height: auto;
  margin: 25px;
  display: flex;
}

.carousel {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vh;
  /*   overflow:hidden; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel .carousel-item {
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(70%, transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));
}

.carousel .carousel-item:first-child .carousel-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel .carousel-item .carousel-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel .carousel-item .carousel-content {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* temp css below */

body {
  background: #2C374A;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  color: #444;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.button:hover,
.button:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.button:active,
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="button" onclick="selectNext()">Next</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="selectCurrent()">Select</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="selectPrev()">Prev</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Make a Call</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#0E6DE8;border:10px solid #78B1FA">Slide One</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Message</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#D90080;border:10px solid #E357A9">Slide Two</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Picture</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#FEC601;border:10px solid #FFDD64">Slide Three</div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-title">Send a Video</div>
      <div class="carousel-content" style="background:#3DB365;border:10px solid #90E0AB">Slide Four</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't see prev and next buttons. Is animation still working ?

Comment: Yes it is, check I placed the button on the top for convenience.

Comment: Actually it was sliding animation if you look at my example which doesn't work now anymore. I think that's the problem, I cannot figure out how to make it responsive while using position `abosulute` and `left` properties.

Comment: Thanks I got idea from your snippet. What I did is not add position absolute in CSS but apply it via javascript *later after boxes have rendered*, this way responsiveness works and value for `left` property is appropriate. Result here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600533/css-make-children-inside-parent-responsive

Comment: Yes that's perfect. Adding `position:absolute` in JS won't affect the responsiveness. Very sensible approach.